# Java - criteria API - usage outside of JPA

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I am using JPA 2.1 and was trying to reference metamodels outside of a JPA scope just as a simple way to get the field names for a given class.  However, when I do that, I end up getting an NPE:

```
System.out.println("attribute:" + Job_.id.getName());
```

I was expecting to get "attribute:id" in stdout, but instead I get an NPE.  If I use the same in a criteria query (filtering on the id), I get what I expect.

The Job_ class is nothing special right, it is just a static class that I should be able to reference.  If I look at how I'm using the criteria API, it is identical.  I pass in an Attribute or SingularAttribute and that tells JPA what attribute I care to filter on.

Should I be able to do this, or am I doing something drastically wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields in static metamodels are filled in runtime, by your JPA provider (hibernate, eclipselink...).

There is a way to get a property name with lambda expressions using SerializedLambda.

Look at this: https://github.com/benjiman/lambda-type-references
And this: http://benjiweber.co.uk/blog/2013/12/28/typesafe-database-interaction-with-java-8/

Comment: Thanks, once I use or setup hibernate, it works as expected.